# Register jupyter variable from an another module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I created simple cell magic function for calling AWS Athena

```
import awswrangler as wr
import inspect
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.magic import (register_line_magic, register_cell_magic,
                                register_line_cell_magic)


@register_cell_magic
def athena(line, cell):
    """
    Execute athena query and return the result as a pandas dataframe

    Usage:
    >>> %%athena <database> [<destination_var>]

    :param line:
    :param cell:
    :return:
    """

    args = []
    if line:
        args = line.split()
    df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(cell, database=args[0])
    if len(args) > 1:
        globals()[args[1]] = df
    else:
        return df
```

and put it into separate module that's imported from the Jupyter notebook.

The problem is that the resulting dataframe is not registered into the global variables of the jupyter notebook, but to the globals of that module.

When I inline this stanza in the notebook and execute it within it then the variable is properly registered and accessible.

What's the correct way of registering that dataframe into the Jupyter's globals?

I tried several hacks using inspect library to get the importer module but it didn't work for me and I fell like this is an invalid solution.

Isn't there any way to get the notebooks globals properly or even some special context that allows me to register variables properly?

Comment: After reading some documentation, using globals was invalid. I decorated the function with `@needs_local_scope` and used `local_ns` as the proper `globals`

Answer (score 0):

After reading https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html I found the answer, so proper implementation is

```
import awswrangler as wr
from IPython.core.magic import (register_cell_magic,
                                needs_local_scope)


@register_cell_magic
@needs_local_scope
def athena(line, cell, local_ns=None):
    """
    Execute athena query and return the result as a pandas dataframe

    Usage:
    >>> %%athena <database> [<destination_var>]

    :param line:
    :param cell:
    :return:
    """

    print(local_ns.keys())

    args = []
    if line:
        args = line.split()
    df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(cell, database=args[0])
    if len(args) > 1:
        local_ns[args[1]] = df
    else:
        return df
```